# PhoneGap Build: Viewport not working on Android

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

No matter what I try I can't get the viewport tag to work with a fixed width.

This is my current effort:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

It works fine on the iPhone simulator running iOS5. I'm testing it on Android 4.1.

I've read about including some code in the Java .onCreate(); method, but using PhoneGap Build I don't have access to this.

My app is here: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/188638

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here using PhoneGap Build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925836/make-content-to-scale-and-fit-with-phonegap-using-viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below view port

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/`>
```